# Html and PHP Concatenation in URL String

Tags: php, html, concatenation

Whats wrong with this HTML / PHP - just doesnt look right - Is there a better way to concatenate html and php variables into url string ???

```
<a href="movie_night_del.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>&mov=<?php echo $mov ?>">Click here to delete</a>
```

Comment: no need of concatenation here, use as <?php echo "movie_night_del.php?id=$id&mov=$mov"; ?>

Comment: there's nothing wrong with it. you've just chosen to echo each varaible separately. you can choose to build bigger strings in php and output the whole thing, instead of small chunks. how you do that is up to you, it's purely a code readability issue, which boils down to opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to do it in "more php" way, for example:

```
echo '<a href="movie_night_del.php?id=' . $id . '&mov=' . $mov . '">Click here to delete</a>'
//or
echo "<a href='movie_night_del.php?id={$id}&mov={$mov}'>Click here to delete</a>"
//or escaping "
echo "<a href=\"movie_night_del.php?id={$id}&mov={$mov}\">Click here to delete</a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is nothing wrong doing it like that but your values could break the query string if they contain characters that need to be encoded.

For example the `&` and the `=` have special meanings, so if they could appear in your variable values, they would break the query string.

You can escape individual values using:

```
... &mov=<?php echo urlencode($mov) ?> ....
```

Or you could have php build and encode your string automatically using [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$data = array(
  'id' => $id,
  'mov' => $mov
);
$url = 'movie_night_del.php?' . http_build_query($data);
```

Perhaps the last option is what you were looking for.