# Making AJAX Call or CURL or How to send data with parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

A company sends me a "pixel" to help me to generate a few leads.

They send me a php file like this:

http://www.blabla.com/custom.php?email=XXXXX

They need from me, to pass the email in the "email value"

The first thing i did , was, using jquery, get the values written in the inputs

...
...

and make a call to a php file that i created

```
$.get("http://www.example.com/catchlead.php?firstname="+$('#firstname').val()+"&correo="+$('#email').val());
```

and in my php there is a function:

```
function insertar_lead($name = NULL, $email = NULL) {

echo '<img src="http://www.blabla.com/custom.php?email='.$email.'" />';

$insert = "INSERT INTO what_i_catch (name,email) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $email . "')";
 $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query($insert);
 $GLOBALS['mysqli']->close();
 }

 if ($name != NULL && $email != NULL) {
 insertar_lead($name, $email);
 }
```

---

It inserts in my db, but is not sending the email here:

```
echo '<img src="http://www.blabla.com/custom.php?email='.$email.'" />';
```

I tried using curl, and the same hapenning,

Is AJAX the better way?

Help Me!

Thanks.,

Comment: Go to the URL in your browser and inspect the Network tab. Look for the response and check your parameters.

Comment: When is your `insertar_lead` function called? What does the data being passed to it look like (`$name` and `$email`)?

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Not even escaping the inputs is as safe as one would hope.

Comment: $url = "www.example.com/email={$email}"

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
echo "<img src=\"http://www.blabla.com/custom.php?email={$email}\">"
```

More approaches can be found here [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927333/html-and-php-concatenation-in-url-string)